# Understanding errors in Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I am fairly new to C so I've been honing my skills by working on this program which recovers passwords by searching two text files for matching hashes. When I attempt to compile this program, I get the following error.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As such, I attempted to debug my program using valgrind. As I'm rather new to C I do not quite understand the errors in my program. The errors are as follows.

Error 1: Possible memory leaks.

```
552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
 at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
 linux.so)
by 0x4EA7CDC: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:69)
by 0x4008E7: matchfile (in /home/st2411/test)
by 0x400873: main (in /home/st2411/test)
```

Error 2: Invalid read of size 1. I find this error rather difficult to understand as it does not indicate which line the error occurred

```
Invalid read of size 1
at 0x4EE4070: __strstr_sse2_unaligned (strstr-sse2-unaligned.S:22)
by 0x4009DA: matchfile (in /home/st2411/test)
by 0x400873: main (in /home/st2411/test)
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

My Code Is as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
//Declaring Functions to match word in file
int matchfile(char *shadowfilename, char 
*hashtablefilename);//shadowfilename for shadow.txt hashtablefilename for hash table

void UsageInfo(char *shadowfile, char * hashtablefile );//Display usage info on arguments for program

void UsageInfo(char *shadowfile, char * hashtablefile) {
    printf("Usage: %s %s <shadowfile> <hashtable>\n", shadowfile, hashtablefile);
    
}

//main function.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result;
        int errcode;
//Display format for user to enter arguments and
//End program if user does not enter exactly 3 arguments
    if(argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        UsageInfo(argv[1],argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    
    system("cls");
//Pass command line arguments into searchstringinfile
    result = matchfile(argv[1], argv[2]);
    
//Display error message
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errcode);
        exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
//Declaring Functions to match word in file


int matchfile(char *shadowfilename, char *hashtablefilename){
    //Declare file containing user account and hashed password
    FILE *shadowfile;
    //Declare file containing list of words and corresponding hash values

    FILE *hashtable;
    //char variables to extract text from files

    char strshadow[MAXCHAR];

    char strhash[MAXCHAR];

//read from file containing user account and hashed password

shadowfile = fopen(shadowfilename, "r");

//error message if file does not exist

if (shadowfile == NULL){
    printf("Could not open file %s",shadowfilename);
    return 1;
}

//read from file containing list of words and corresponding hash values

hashtable = fopen(hashtablefilename, "r");

//error message if file does not exist

if (hashtable == NULL){
    printf("Could not open file %s",hashtablefilename);
    return 1;
}

const char ch = '$';
//char variables to extract hash values

//char *strshadowvalues for shadow file;

//char *strhashvalues for hash table file;
//Valgrind detected an error here
char *strshadowvalues;
char *strhashvalues;

    //variable to check line number for matched
int linenumber = 1;
    //Variable to count match results
int search_result = 0;
while (fgets(strshadow, MAXCHAR, shadowfile) != NULL && fgets(strhash, MAXCHAR, hashtable) != NULL){


    strshadowvalues = strchr(strshadow, ch);
    strhashvalues = strchr(strhash, ch);
            //Matching hashes line-by-line

    if((strstr(strshadowvalues,strhashvalues)) != NULL) {
        //Display lines in which matched hash is found
        
        printf("A match found on line: %d\n", linenumber);
        //Display matching hash in shadow file

                    printf("Shadow:\n%s\n", strshadow);
                    //Display matching hash in shadow file

        printf("Hash: \n%s\n", strhash);
        
        
        search_result++;
    }//Display message if no match

    if((strstr(strshadowvalues,strhashvalues)) == NULL|| strshadowvalues==NULL || strhashvalues==NULL) {
                printf("No password found ");
            }
    linenumber++;
}

//close file
fclose(shadowfile);
return 0;
}
```

If someone could explain to me where I've gone wrong and guide me on how to fix them, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Compile your code with `-g` will give you more information.. Like line number ;).

Comment: "Invalid read of size 1" => look like you are overextend of one char ? Useful information.

Comment: "Address 0x0" => NULL pointer ?

Comment: Man of strstr => "These functions return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if the substring is not found.".

Comment: Did you check if `strshadowvalues` and `strhashvalues` are not null before send them here `strstr(strshadowvalues,strhashvalues)` => no => here your error ALWAYS CHECK return value => you're welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much. My program works fine and I have o errors in my error summary. Should I worry about the heap summary which indicates that 552 bytes are still reachable ?

Comment: No still reachable mean that it should be ok (hint: you probably stop your program with ctrl+c so your `fclose()` has not be call but in normal execution it will, try to test you program with normal termination)

Comment: You `fopen()` two files, but `fclose()` only one of them. That's where your memory leak comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what happens here:

```
strshadowvalues = strchr(strshadow, ch);
strhashvalues = strchr(strhash, ch);
        //Matching hashes line-by-line

if((strstr(strshadowvalues,strhashvalues)) != NULL) {
    //Display lines in which matched hash is found
```

when there is no `$` found in the line or when one of the two strings (or both, for that matter) are empty.  The answer is, `strstr()` will return a null pointer.  When you try to print that with a `%s` format string, you end up in the realm of undefined behavior and a segmentation fault.

I'll leave it to you to find the memory leak that Valgrind mentions, but this is why it is telling you that `Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`